# Needs ad skip option into videojs-ima

Tags: video.js

I am using videojs-ima plugin to trigger my vast tags, its is working fine with ads, but not showing the Ad Skip button to skip the ad .

Can anyone help me 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**videojs-ima** support skippable ads via the VAST response, you can add a skippable offset to your linear creative.

add attribute to Linear `<Linear skipoffset="00:00:05">…</Linear>`. More details here http://www.iab.net/media/file/VASTv3.0.pdf